# Why do my axis mappings to remap the MoveForward and MoveRight keys not seem to have any effect in-game on Unreal Editor 4.27.2?

Tags: unreal-4, input, unreal, axis

Since I have an azerty keyboard instead of a qwerty one I'm trying to remap wasd to zqsd for the in-game playing in Unreal Editor 4.27.2.

I've started a new blank c++ project with starter content. Then I went to Project Settings -> Engine - Input -> Axis Mappings.

This is what my new axis mappings look like:
[image]

However, no matter what, when clicking Play, the camera movements will only respond to wasd and completely ignore the axis mappings which I put there. I build, compiled and tried restarting the editor but to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created anything for the program to inhabit.  Whether this is a pawn or a character, you need something in your Game Mode -> Default Pawn Class, otherwise what you're moving around is just the level camera.

Answer (score 0):

Eazy way, you can go to your character detail settings, search 'auto possess player', then change to player0.